# Se puede cerrar un hilo desde otro hilo en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++20

Puedo finalizar la ejecución de un hilo desde otro?
Actualmente estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto de un juego que trata de introducir palabras, no os aburriré hablando de como funciona.

La cuestión es que en este he querido hacer un modo contrarreloj, pero no sé como hacer para finalizar el bucle principal del juego/hilo principal cuando finaliza mi temporizador, hecho en otro hilo para que ejecute al mismo tiempo. Siempre me queda un último imput aún habiendo pasado el tiempo de ejecución.

PD: una opción como las task de c#? Algo así?

He pensado que a lo mejor hay algún comando, que aún no he encontrado, que me permita hacer algún tipo de exit o algo, pero no se me ocurre.

Gracias de ante mano, no tengo mucha idea de programación todavía.

Comment: Por lo que sé, con la clase [`jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) se pueden crear hilos que se pueden parar. Aunque a mí me resulta más cómodo poner un `while (seguir)`, de modo que si quieres parar el hilo estableces `seguir` en `false`. El detalle es que el hilo no parará hasta que termine la última iteración.

Comment: Me parece que no hay forma de interrumpir un `std::cin` desde otro hilo, es por ello que siempre tendrás el comportamiento observado.

Answer (score 0):

Un hilo finaliza cuando el código que está ejecutando finaliza. Por lo tanto puedes cerrar (finalizar) un hilo desde otro hilo, basta con que hilo interno acabe de hacer su trabajo, puedes verlo en este ejemplo:

```cpp
void contar(unsigned u, unsigned tarea)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::cout << "Empiezo tarea " << tarea << '\n';

    for (auto i = 0u; i != u; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << tarea << ": " << i << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }
    std::cout << "Acabo tarea " << tarea << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto externo = std::thread{[]
    {
        auto interno = std::thread{[]{ contar(5, 2); }};
        contar(10, 1);
        interno.join();
    }};

    externo.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Que produce [la siguiente salida](https://wandbox.org/permlink/heKEOCOHfo30QV0W):

```
Empiezo tarea 1
1: 0
Empiezo tarea 2
2: 0
1: 1
2: 1
1: 2
2: 2
1: 3
2: 3
1: 4
2: 4
1: 5
Acabo tarea 2
1: 6
1: 7
1: 8
1: 9
Acabo tarea 1
```

Fíjate que llamamos a `thread::join` antes de salir del contexto en que se crea un hilo, esto es necesario porque el programa falla si se destruye un objeto `thread` antes de que acabe su trabajo, si usas `jthread` el `::join` lo hace automáticamente en el destructor.

Pero apuesto a que todo esto no responde a tu pregunta. Por lo que me parece entender, necesitas finalizar un hilo cuando acaba un temporizador que se controla en otro hilo. Para ello podrías sincronizar tus hilos mediante una "[*condition variable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)", te animo a que investigues esa utilidad.